# Cohomology of pushforward and higher pushforward sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, complex-manifolds

I am reading through Peters-Steenbrink *Mixed Hodge structures* and I am having some trouble understanding what definitions of cohomology and hypercohomology are getting used. Let $U$ be a complex manifold. Its cohomology is (I think) by definition the cohomology of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U$, which by definition is computed by taking an injective resolution, applying the global sections functor component-wise to the resolution and taking cohomology. This is the same as seeing $\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U$ as a complex concentrated in degree zero and taking hypercohomology:

$$ H^k(U;\mathbb{C}) :=  H^k(U;\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U) := \mathbb{H}^k(U;\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U) := H^k \circ R\Gamma(U,-)\ (\cdots \to 0 \to \underline{\mathbb{C}}_U \to 0 \to \ldots). $$

On the other hand, we can have some good compactification $j: U \to X$ and we want to work with sheaves on $X$. In this case I would notice that $\Gamma(U,-) = \Gamma(X,-) \circ j_*$ and hence

$$ H^k(U;\mathbb{C}) = H^k \circ R\Gamma(U,-) (\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U) = H^k \circ R\Gamma(X,-) \circ Rj_* (\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U) = \mathbb{H}^k(X; Rj_*(\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U)). $$

Since the holomorphic de Rham complex $\Omega^\bullet_U$ is a resolution of $\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U$, they are equal in the derived category, and hence

$$ H^k(U; \mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{H}^k(X; Rj_*\Omega^\bullet_u) $$

However this is **not** what I understand from the book (see for instance Proposition 4.3). Instead, they seem to take for granted that the cohomology of $U$ is the hypercohomology of $j_*\Omega^\bullet_U$, which I understand to be the component-wise application of the functor $j_*$ to the complex $\Omega^\bullet_U$.

What am I missing?

---

EDIT: I guess that I can rephrase my question as follows. Which of the following is true:

$$ \mathbb{H}^k(U, \mathcal{F}^\bullet) = \mathbb{H}^k(X, j_*\mathcal{F}^\bullet) \qquad \text{or} \qquad \mathbb{H}^k(U, \mathcal{F}^\bullet) = \mathbb{H}^k(X, Rj_*\mathcal{F}^\bullet)? $$

The argument above seems to tell me that the second one is true, but the book seems to imply that the first one is true.

Comment: In general $j_*$ is not exact and the usual relation is the second one : $\mathbb{H}^k(U;\mathcal{F}^\bullet)=\mathbb{H}^k(X,Rj_*\mathcal{F}^\bullet)$. However, in the case of Peter-Steenbrink, $j_*$ is the inclusion of the complement of a divisor and hence is exact on coherent sheaves. This means that you have $R^pj_*\Omega^q_U=0$ for all $p>0$, hence $Rj_*\Omega^\bullet = j_*\Omega^\bullet$. Note however that $Rj_ *\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U\neq j_*\underline{\mathbb{C}}_U$, this is not a contradiction as $j_*$ does not preserve quasi-isomorphism.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $j$ is an open embedding, $j_*$ is exact, and $Rj_* = j_*$.

Comment: No $j_*$ is not exact. For instance, if $j:\mathbb{C}^*\to\mathbb{C}$, $R^1j_*\mathbb{Z}$ is a skyscraper sheaf supported at zero.

Comment: You are right of course.